# Sorting Edges in a Data Structures Graph

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, nodes

I have a graph with edges that are interconnected. How I would go about sorting the edges of the nodes in the graph from low to high by weight number?

```
edges = {
    ("a", "b"): 1,
    ("a", "c"): 7,
    ("a", "d"): 3,
    ("b", "c"): 2,
    ("f", "b"): 6,
    ("c", "d"): 1,
    ("c", "e"): 8,
    ("d", "e"): 4,
    ("e", "f"): 1,
    ("f", "g"): 3,
}
```

Where a-g are nodes and the number is the weight of the edge. Written in python.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `dict` keys into a `list`, and then sort the `list`.

```
edges = {('a', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'c'): 7, ('a', 'd'): 3, ('b', 'c'): 2, ('f', 'b'): 6, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('c', 'e'): 8, ('d', 'e'): 4, ('e', 'f'): 1, ('f', 'g'): 3}
edgeList = sorted(edges.keys(), key = edges.get)
```

`edges.keys()` is a `dict` method that will get you a `dict_keys` object. Basically a wrapper object around a list of the keys used in your `dict`. The second parameter to the `sorted` function is the criteria that will be used to sort the iterable provided in the first parameter of `sorted`.